# Where can I find the source code for J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me

I am currently working in J2ME. I would like to link the source code of J2ME with my Eclipse installation so that I can go through the contents of it and also it will help me in debugging.

I am quite used to this when the source code of J2SE was (is) available in jar format and you just need to link it to Eclipse.

Could you please provide me the link to the download of the jar. Is it free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the core issue is that Java SE and the JDK is now open source, where J2ME is not.  So, even getting Sun's implementations of J2ME might be a bit tough at this time.

There must be a reason, but not sure why they wouldn't open source the J2ME implementation as well.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple implementations of the CLDC VM. So you might have a hard time finding the sources. Also most of the VM do not support debugging the system classes. If you want to see the CLDC sources, SUNs implementation is open-sourced on dev.java.net [PhoneME Project](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using a decompiler like [JADclipse](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/) instead?